# PyQt, separar método de una subventana en otro archivo para importarla

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

Estoy haciendo un ejemplo sencillo de pyqt. Una QMainWindow que tiene un solo boton, el cual invoca a un Qwidget, el cual tiene un boton y una linea de texto. Cuando se pulse el boton del Qwidget, lo que hace es desactivar la linea de texto (he elegido esto, como podia haber elegido enviar un texto a la linea).

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QDialog
from PyQt5 import uic

class subvent(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi('ventana.ui', self)

class Principal(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi('conexion.ui', self)

        self.boton.clicked.connect(self.invocar)
        self.Sub = subvent()
        self.Sub.boton.clicked.connect(self.ocultar)

    def ocultar(self):
        self.Sub.linea.setEnabled(False)

    def invocar(self):
        self.Sub.exec_()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ventana = Principal()
ventana.show()
app.exec_()
mi codigo
```

Con las anteriores lineas me funciona lo que yo quiero, pero me interesa que el comando:

```
self.Sub.linea.setEnabled(False)
```

Que es el que da la orden de desactivar la linea de texto, este en otro archivo, para después importarla (esto es por que tengo pensado hacer un programa y ahora es tan solo una linea, pero mas adelante serán mucha mas, y de esa manera lo tendré mas organizo el programa, que si esta todo al pegote, en un solo archivo).

Lo que hago es importar desde el archivo "meca", donde estará separado toda las funciones del QWidget. Realizo la conexión de botón de la QWidget y uso el método importado

El codigo modificado:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QDialog
from PyQt5 import uic

#importamos el archivo
import meca

class subvent(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi('ventana.ui', self)

class Principal(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi('conexion.ui', self)

        self.boton.clicked.connect(self.invocar)
        self.Sub = subvent()

        # realizamos la conexion del boton de la Widget
        self.Sub.boton.clicked.connect(self.ocultar)

    def ocultar(self):
        #Cargo el metodo del archivo meca
        self.accion = meca.ocultar()

    def invocar(self):
        self.Sub.exec_()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ventana = Principal()
ventana.show()
app.exec_()
```

Codigo de meca.py

```
def ocultar():    
    Sub.linea.setEnabled(False)
```

He realizado varias combinaciones quitando y poniendo cosas, pero siempre me da error. Se que funciona, ya que si en def ocultar, cambio el comando por print('hola'), cada vez que pulso en el boton del QWidget, me devuelve la terminal 'hola'.

Seguro que sera un tontería, pero ya no se mas donde mirar.

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1):

Es posible usar métodos guardados en otro módulo y vas bien encaminado. El problema está en que ese método se aplica sobre otro atributo de la clase (`Sub`) que es una instancia de la clase `subvent` pero el método está definido en un lugar externo a la clase con su propio espacio de nombres y simplemente no sabe que es `Sub` en la función de `meca`.

Una posible solución es pasarle la clase como parametro:

**main.py:**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QDialog
from PyQt5 import uic

#importamos el archivo
import meca


class subvent(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi('ventana.ui', self)


class Principal(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi('conexion.ui', self)

        self.boton.clicked.connect(self.invocar)
        self.Sub = subvent()

        # realizamos la conexion del boton de la Widget
        self.Sub.boton.clicked.connect(self.ocultar)

    def ocultar(self):
        meca.ocultar(self)

    def invocar(self):
        self.Sub.exec_()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ventana = Principal()
ventana.show()
app.exec_()
```

**meca.py:**

```
def ocultar(self):
    self.Sub.linea.setEnabled(False)
```

---

De todas formas, te aconsejaría que en vez de guardar lós métodos en otro módulo, guardes los distintos widgets con sus métodos en módulos separados. Por ejemplo, en este caso metes en un módulo aparte la clase `subvent` y el método `ocultar`,ya que se aplica sobre elementos de esta clase, lo defines aquí.

**main.py:**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QDialog
from PyQt5 import uic

#importamos el archivo
import subvent


class Principal(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi('conexion.ui', self)

        self.boton.clicked.connect(self.invocar)
        self.Sub = subvent.Subvent()

    def invocar(self):
        self.Sub.exec_()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ventana = Principal()
ventana.show()
app.exec_()
```

**subvent.py**:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog
from PyQt5 import uic


class Subvent(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi('ventana.ui', self)

        self.boton.clicked.connect(self.ocultar)

    def ocultar(self):
        self.linea.setEnabled(False)
```

Creo que de esta forma queda más organizado y comprensible para terceras personas, además de ser más reutilizable, pero bueno eso ya son opiniones personales.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me gusta tu segunda opción, como tu dices es más organizado y comprensible.

Comment: Además tiene la ventaja que puedes reutilizar la clase en otra momento o en otra GUI con solo importarla e instanciarla. si necesitas que haga algo nuevo o diferencte pues la sobreescrives simplemente.